# Cannot Delete Post With Dropdown Link

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to delete a user post with a drop-down link "Delete Post." I feel I have the logic right as I want to remove the photo as well. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can instruct me, it would be appreciated.

**PostsController:**

```php
<?php

public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    unlink(public_path() . $post->photo->file);
    $post->delete();

    return redirect('/home');
}
```

**web.php:**

```
Route::delete('/home', 'PostsController@destroy')->name('deletePost');
```

**home.blade.php:**

```
<div class="card-header">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button style="float: right;" type="button" class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit Post</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('deletePost') }}">Delete Post</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>{{$post->user->name}}</div>
    <div id="post-date">{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you are clicking the link, you can just make GET request. but you can create a hidden form with DELETE method (read https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing), and bind your link with form submit. and, i suppose, you have to set post id to you route('deletePost')

Answer (score 0):

just change your route to

```
Route::get('/home', 'PostsController@destroy')->name('deletePost');
```

since tag `a` make http GET request and you're listing on DELETE request

Comment: I made the changes to the web route. Now i get the error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::destroy(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Comment: yeah that because you made the controller function expect id which will be provided by the route but you did't put placeholder for id in the route , 
you should make your route like this `Route::get('/home/{id}', 'PostsController@destroy')->name('deletePost');` and you should call route function with the id you want to delete `route('deletePost' , ["id" => 1 ])`